# GetElementsByTagName fails although getElementById works

Tags: javascript

The following script works perfectly, but when I try it with `GetElementsByTagName` it fails.  An `ID` can only be used once and I want to use it for (`'a', h1, h2`).

Thoughts, ideas or solutions are welcome.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var t = document.getElementById('test');  
    var z = 'rgb('+ (Math.floor(Math.random() * 184)) + ',' 
                  + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 102)) + ',' 
                  + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 184)) + ')';                    
    t.style.color = z
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Show the code that *doesn't* work. We can't tell how to fix the code that already works.

Comment: Can you post the full code or prepare a plunk

Comment: Try `querySelectorAll` and iterate through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementById return only single element but getElementsByTagName return array. You can use this code.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
var t = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');  
var z = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 184)) + ',' 
                 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 102)) + ',' 
                     + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 184)) + ')';
for(var i=0;i < t.length; i++)
{
  t[i].style.color = z
}

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Don't use a `for in` loop to iterate over `t`. `console.log(i)` will show you it also will iterate over the `length`, `item` and `namedItem` properties.

Comment: Yes you are right @Cerbrus, I edited the answer.

Comment: Perfect!  Adding in the for loop fixed it!!